# How to install a ClickOnce application for a specific user

Tags: clickonce

We have created a ClickOnce application for internal use. Due to our IT department's security requirements, installations for most users are only possible using the credentials of a specific account. The problem is that when we use this specific installation account, the ClickOnce application is not actually installed for the user that is logged in, but for the installation account.

Is there a way to install the ClickOnce application for the logged-in user? (It seems that installing the application for "All users" is not possible by design.)

Comment: This document might help unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php Also include: Use Install Sheild if you want to develop MSI/EXE installer programm. Link from where you can get it: flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ashwin. This seems to be a limitation indeed of the ClickOnce Technology. Too bad; this means we will have to build our own solution in order to both install the application for all users and get the benefit of automatic updates. It seems rather awkward and unnecessesary that MS would limit the functionality of ClickOnce in such an arbitrary way....